# Using PHP to filter Posts by Category

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a site in Wordpress that featured a list of events (posts) at can be categorized into different cities (Categories).

I'm aiming to be able to filter these events (posts) by the city (Category) in which they appear.

How do I filter the events by category?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

**Wordpress Categories assigned to Event posts**

`Event = cat4`
`City A = cat6`
`City B = cat5`
`Uncategorized = cat7`

```
        <div class="row justify-content-center row-padding" id="brands">
            <div class="col-9">  
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-10">
                        <div class="animatedParent animateOnce">
                            <?php if( get_field('brands_title') ):?>
                                <h1 class="mb-3 animated fadeInUpShort"><span><?php the_field('events_title');?></span></h1>
                            <?php endif;?>
                            <?php if( get_field('brands_intro') ):?>
                                <h4 class="mb-5 animated fadeInUpShort"><?php the_field('events_intro');?></h4>
                            <?php endif;?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-1">
                    </div>    
                    <div class="col-1 align-self-center animatedParent animateOnce" style="z-index:99;">
                        <div class="dropdown animated fadeInUpShort">
                            <button class="btn filter-button dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            Filter by City
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">City A</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">City B</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Uncategorized</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                       
                <div class="row justify-content-center animatedParent animateOnce" data-sequence="100">
                    <?php 
                        $brandPosts = new WP_Query('cat=4&posts_per_page=99');

                        if ($brandPosts->have_posts()) {
                            $i=1;
                            while ($brandPosts->have_posts()) {
                                $brandPosts->the_post();
                                ?>  
                                <div class="col-4 animated fadeIn mb-5 pb-3" data-id="<?php echo $i; ?>">            
                                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                        <div class="col-12 text-center">
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" class="img-fluid rounded-circle mb-3"></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-10 offset-2">
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h2 class="mb-0"><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
                                            <p><?php echo excerpt(16); ?></p>
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="see-more">See More</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>     
                                </div>     
                                <?php 
                            $i++;
                            }
                    } else {
                        //echo 'No content found';
                    } 

                    wp_reset_postdata();

                    ?>  
                </div>
            </div>              
        </div>
```

[image: events]

Comment: Where is the Javascript that you've written to hide/show the category entries?

Comment: _“Any help would be greatly appreciated”_ - we don’t know what kind of help _exactly_ you need, based on just that. Please go read [ask]. You need to ask _specific_ questions.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a custom WordPress template for example country-posts-archive.php and implement a custom post query with the desired filters.

```
$categories_args = array(
    'orderby' => 'menu_order', //prefered order
    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', // the taxonomy we want to get terms of
    'exclude' => '17, 69', //exclude something
);
```

and then use it in a wp post loop, also you can play around in orderby.php

Or, simply non-coding way just use side Plugin, for example:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/blog-designer/

Also you can do it in a bit tricky way, populate dropdown with links to archive pages e.g.

```
www.website.com/category/your-category
```